# Rename files on android rooted phone using script

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator

I have an android phone and I keep downloading some media files which I would not want to appear in gallery. Don't think me absurd here. In order to accomplish this task, I have written a small & easy script. Here it is.

```
echo "Below files will be hidden."
for fName in `ls /storage/extSdCard/Download/*.mp4`
do
echo $fName
mv -f $fName `basename $fName .mp4`.bak
done
```

When I execute this script using "File Explorer" application's "Script executor" utility with root user, I get an error message as below.

```
mv: can't create 'abc.mp4': Read-only file system
```

I assume "root" user has free run in unix/linux based systems. Can anybody guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The folder that abc.mp4 intended to be placed in, is probably Read-only for all users. Use the command `ls -l` in parent folder to check.

If you want the abc.mp4 in the folder, use `chmod` to change the folder permission first. For example, if the folder is named `folder`:

```
chmod +wx folder
```

w for write permission, x for execute permission. You can run your script smoothly after the permission change.

Comment: That's not the case. The folder I am trying to perform some operation belongs to user : system & group is root. Also, file permissions are rwxrwxr-x. Also, I tried to change permission of the folder using "Root explorer" and it does not allow me. So, it will boils down to user permission. What makes me wonder is, how dare it does not allow "root" user to change permissions. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @SurendraRaut Your comment reminds me about your folder path `/storage/extSdCard/Download/*.mp4`, which seems to be an SD card. Is this SD card set to be **Write Protected**?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply but I don't have a write protection switch on my SD card so that it ruled out too. That could have been caught earlier as I have been taking back ups of my ROM on SD card ever since I bought it. Anyway, thanks for ruling out those options.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built-in option for 'hiding' media files such as .MP3 and .JPG from appearing in the gallery of Media Applications.

All you need to do is create a blank file called `.nomedia` and place it in the same directory as the media files you wish to 'hide'.

So depending on your requirements it may be easier to change your script to just move the files to a different directory and place a `.nomedia` file in it.